# Build a graph with Twitter stream and query using Apache Flink

Tags: twitter, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I listen to Twitter stream and successful with extracting data I want from tweets. Now I want to keep building a graph with the extracted info, like

```
 (user)--[tweets]-->(tweet) 

 (tweet)--[mentions]-->(user)

 (tweet)--[tagged]-->(hashtag)
```

While this graph keep building over the time, I want to run queries over this graph. How can I do this with Apache Flink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some more digging in to the forums and JIRA, I found [gelly-streaming](https://github.com/vasia/gelly-streaming) matching my needs.

With it, we can do create a `GraphStream`,

`GraphStream<Long, NullValue, NullValue> graph = new SimpleEdgeStream<>(getEdgesDataSet(env), env);`

Examples : https://github.com/vasia/gelly-streaming/tree/master/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/graph/streaming/example

---

Here are some other relevant links.

On Apache Flink mailing list : http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Graph-with-stream-of-updates-td5166.html

Vasia Kalavri's talk on Graphs as Streams: https://berlinbuzzwords.de/session/graphs-streams-rethinking-graph-processing-streaming-era